# Javascript - EXTjs Accessing Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

Again, i'm quite new to Javascript and Extjs.

code:

```
 var test = [
        {
            id: 0,
            test: 'Hello'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            test: 'World'
        }
    ];
```

how do I get the ID of each instance?.

Thanks  for the reply.

Regards,
Ronel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you mean:

```
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  console.log( test[i].id);
}
```

or

```
console.log( test[0].id); //for first
console.log( test[1].id); //for second
```

in Extjs, you can use iterator function:

```
Ext.each(test, function(val, index) {
  console.log(val.id)
});
```

OR

```
Ext.pluck(test, 'id'); //returns [0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for giving different ways to retrieve it. I got it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.each(test, function(item) {
   console.log(item.id); 
});
```